# String search in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string, parsing, nsstring

Given a string like this:

```
http://files.domain.com/8aa55fc4-3015-400e-80f5-390997b43cf9/c07cb0d2-b7d7-4bfd-b0c3-6f43571e3c29-MyFile.jpg
```

I need to just locate the string "MyFile", and also tell what kind of image it is (.jpg or .png). How can I accomplish this?

The only thing I can think of is to search backward for the first four characters to get the file extension, then keep searching backward until I find the first hyphen, and assume the file name itself doesn't have any hyphens. But I don't know how to do that. Is there a better way?

Comment: `[string pathExtension]` - for extension

Comment: Have you tried reading the spec for NSString?  There are a bunch of functions there you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[myString lastPathComponent]` will get the filename.
`[myString pathExtension]` will get the extension.

To get the suffix of the filename, I think you'll have to roll your own parse.  Is it always the string after the last dash and before the extension?

If so, here's an idea:

```
- (NSString *)lastLittleBitOfTheFilenameFrom:(NSString *)filename {

    NSInteger fnStart = [filename rangeOfString:@"-" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location + 1;
    NSInteger fnEnd = [filename rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;

    // might need some error checks here depending on what you expect in the original url
    NSInteger length = fnEnd - fnStart;

    return [filename substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(fnStart, length)];
}
```

Or, thanks to @Chuck ...

```
// even more sensitive to unexpected input, but nice and tiny ...

- (NSString *)lastLittleBitOfTheFilenameFrom:(NSString *)filename {
    NSString *nameExt = [[filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject];
    return [[nameExt componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd just do `[[filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject]`. But I'm lazy.

Comment: It's a good thought.  I think we still need to chop off that extension, though.  Could do another componentsSeparatedByString:@".", then take the objectAtIndex:0.  That's cute.

Comment: The NSRangeMake throws an "implicit declaration of function 'NSRangeMake' is invalid in C99.

Comment: But using Chucks's solution combined with lastPathComponent seems to work.

Comment: yes.  sorry.  it's nsmakerange.  this one struct layout function doesn't follow apple's standard pattern.  will edit.  the rest should work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to search for the file name. The search pattern really depends on what you know about the file name. If the "random" numbers and characters before MyFile has a known format, you could take that into account. My proposal below assumes that the file name doesn't contain any minus signs.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression 
                     regularExpressionWithPattern:@"-([:alnum:]*)\\.(jpg|png)$"
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                            error:nil];
// Get the match between the first brackets.
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 
                                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
NSString *fileName = [string substringWithRange:matchRange];
NSLog(@"Filename: %@", fileName);

// Get the extension with a simple NSString method.
NSString *extension = [string pathExtension];
NSLog(@"Extension: %@", extension);
```

Comment: Probably better to search for `@"-(MyFile)\\.(jpg|png)$"`. It's a little more precise.

Comment: This only works for files named "MyFile" though right? It could be any name that doesn't include hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the string in an NSString object, or create it from that string, you may use the rangeOfString method to acomplish both.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html for more details.